# PHP MYSQL and updating data in a table

Tags: php, mysql

Good day, all!
I am trying to figure out how to get this chunk of code to do what I want but it eludes me.

What this script is supposed to do is to look through a database of consignment items, pick out the ones that have sold='n' and list them by item number. It displays all of the items in a list with a "Sell" link at the end of each item row. Once the Buyer Number and Amount are entered, the Sell link is clicked, the UPDATE updates the item and changes sold from 'n' to 'y' and once that happens, the item disappears from the list. It works exactly as I expect, except for one little issue that has eluded me. Each time the page is loaded, it doesn't change the amount and buyernumber, but it does change the sold from 'n' to 'y' for the **first item only** and after that it works as expected, adding the buyernumber and amount to all subsequent items. Until you browse away from it and then it won't do the first item correctly the next time you come back to the page. I have tried all kinds of things to make it work and this is the closest I have to what I want. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<?php

/**
 * Sell an Item
 */

require "../config.php";
require "../common.php";

$success = null;

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  if (!hash_equals($_SESSION['csrf'], $_POST['csrf'])) die();

  try {
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

    $itemnumber = $_POST["submit"];
    $buyernumber = $_POST["buyernumber"];
    $amount = $_POST["amount"];

    $sql = "UPDATE consignitem SET sold='y', amount='$amount', buyernumber='$buyernumber' WHERE sold='n' AND itemnumber = $itemnumber";

    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue(':itemnumber', $itemnumber);
    $statement->bindValue(':buyernumber', $buyernuumber);
    $statement->bindValue(':amount', $amount);
    $statement->bindValue(':sold', $sold);


    $statement->execute();

    $success = "Item successfully updated";
  } catch(PDOException $error) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
  }
}

try {
  $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM consignitem WHERE sold='n'";

  $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
  $statement->execute();

  $result = $statement->fetchAll();
} catch(PDOException $error) {
  echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
}
?>
<?php require "templates/header.php"; ?>

<h2>Mark Items as Sold</h2>

<?php if ($success) echo $success; ?>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<form method="post">
  <input name="csrf" type="hidden" value="<?php echo escape($_SESSION['csrf']); ?>">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Sale Number</th>
        <th>Item Number</th>
        <th>Lot Number</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Item Description</th>
        <th>Reserve</th>
        <th>Seller Number</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Buyer Number</th>
        <th>Sold</th>
        <th>Paid</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Mark</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <?php foreach ($result as $row) : ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo escape($row["salenumber"]); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo escape($row["itemnumber"]); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo escape($row["lotnumber"]); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo escape($row["category"]); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo escape($row["itemdescription"]); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo escape($row["reserve"]); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo escape($row["sellernumber"]); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo escape($row["amount"]); ?><br><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" size="8"></td>
        <td><?php echo escape($row["buyernumber"]); ?><br><input type="text" name="buyernumber" id="buyernumber" size="12"></td>
        <td><?php echo escape($row["sold"]); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo escape($row["paid"]); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo escape($row["date"]); ?> </td>
        <td><button type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo escape($row["itemnumber"]); ?>">Sell</button></td>
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
<br>
<?php require "templates/footer.php"; ?>
```

Comment: are you sure that data gets updated in db?

Comment: You're not binding your values correctly. https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: Mike, The data makes it into the database perfectly from the second item on. Just not for the first one. If you browse away from the page, the next time you come back to it, the first item won't get amount and buyernumber again, but all subsequent do get them. The way it is written, sold gets updated every time even from the first item.

Comment: Dharman, Thank you for responding, but what would need to be done to bind them correctly? It does work fine for the second item on.

Comment: Your `UPDATE` query has no placeholders `:itemnumber`, `:buyernumber`, `"amount`, `:sold`. You should be getting an error when you try to execute it. You also have no variable `$sold`.

Comment: Well dang! Further testing reveals that it isn't working right at all. I just need to rewrite that whole thing. I had it working good but somehow in revision after revision and everything, it has become broken altogether.

Comment: Barmar, yeah, I just forgot to take out the $sold thing there. It was there but not doing anything since the UPDATE statement was explicitly changing it.

Comment: Well, sorry to have bothered you guys with this. . . it isn't working like I thought anyway. Back to the drawing board. I will just delete that thing and start over. I will delete this whole thing if need be. . . just frustrated with this. . . I have pretty much everything else working good but this little snot!

Answer (score 0):

You're repeating the same input names in all thr rows of the form. When the form is submitted, the `$_POST` variables will just contain the value from the last row of the form, not the row that the user clicked the submit button for.

You can give the inputs array-style names that are indexed by `itemnumber`. `$_POST['buyernumber']` and `$_POST['amount']` will then be arrays, and you can use `$_POST['submit']` to get the appropriate array index.

You also need to use placeholders in the SQL that match the placeholders in `bindValue()`, rather than substituting the variables directly in the query.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if (!hash_equals($_SESSION['csrf'], $_POST['csrf'])) die();

    try {
        $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

        $itemnumber = $_POST["submit"];
        $buyernumber = $_POST["buyernumber"][$itemnumber];
        $amount = $_POST["amount"][$itemnumber];

        $sql = "UPDATE consignitem SET sold='y', amount= :amount, buyernumber= :buyernumber WHERE sold='n' AND itemnumber = :itemnumber";

        $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindValue(':itemnumber', $itemnumber);
        $statement->bindValue(':buyernumber', $buyernuumber);
        $statement->bindValue(':amount', $amount);

        $statement->execute();

        $success = "Item successfully updated";
    } catch(PDOException $error) {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
    }
}

try {
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM consignitem WHERE sold='n'";

    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute();

    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
} catch(PDOException $error) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
  }
?>
<?php require "templates/header.php"; ?>

<h2>Mark Items as Sold</h2>

<?php if ($success) echo $success; ?>
<style>
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<form method="post">
      <input name="csrf" type="hidden" value="<?php echo escape($_SESSION['csrf']); ?>">
      <table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>Sale Number</th>
      <th>Item Number</th>
      <th>Lot Number</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Item Description</th>
      <th>Reserve</th>
      <th>Seller Number</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Buyer Number</th>
      <th>Sold</th>
      <th>Paid</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Mark</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      <?php foreach ($result as $row) : ?>
      <tr>
      <td><?php echo escape($row["salenumber"]); ?></td>
<td><?php echo escape($row["itemnumber"]); ?></td>
<td><?php echo escape($row["lotnumber"]); ?></td>
<td><?php echo escape($row["category"]); ?></td>
<td><?php echo escape($row["itemdescription"]); ?></td>
<td><?php echo escape($row["reserve"]); ?></td>
<td><?php echo escape($row["sellernumber"]); ?></td>
<td><?php echo escape($row["amount"]); ?><br><input type="text" name="amount[<?php echo escape($row["itemnumber"]); ?>]" size="8"></td>
      <td><?php echo escape($row["buyernumber"]); ?><br><input type="text" name="buyernumber[<?php echo escape($row["itemnumber"]); ?>]" size="12"></td>
      <td><?php echo escape($row["sold"]); ?></td>
<td><?php echo escape($row["paid"]); ?></td>
<td><?php echo escape($row["date"]); ?> </td>
<td><button type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo escape($row["itemnumber"]); ?>">Sell</button></td>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tbody>
 </table>
 </form>
 <br>
<?php require "templates/footer.php"; ?>
```

Comment: Let me drop that in and see if it works. . . I'll be amazed! And you'll be my hero!

Comment: That did work to some degree but for the Buyernumber and Amount, it just put the word "ARRAY" in those two places in the table. Sold changed to 'y' as expected.

Comment: There is also in the input a tag called id="xxx" and it also has to be in there but it wasn't in your example. like <input type="test" name="somename" id="someid"> do I just repeat what you did for name with the id?
I added that in and it still just says ARRAY in there.

Comment: With your solution, the error log for apache says:
"PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion. . ." and gives a line number and etc. Could that be why it isn't working and what do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to put the array index `[$itemnumber]` in the assignment to `$buynumber` and `$amount`.

Comment: You don't need the IDs in the inputs. IDs are supposed to be unique, and you had the same IDs on every row of the table.

Comment: I realize that but the id is the same as the name and it only pulls the name and id for the row you click the Sell button on. This works perfectly in the other scripts with the exception of not having a place to enter data mid-stream. That is the kicker. I need to be able to add the buyer number and amount before the Sell button is clicked.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You enter them into `<input type="text" name="amount[<?php echo escape($row["itemnumber"]); ?>]" size="8">` and `<input type="text" name="buyernumber[<?php echo escape($row["itemnumber"]); ?>]" size="12">`

Comment: Yes. But as written, when the Sell button is clicked, it changes the 'n' to 'y' as expected and removes that item from the list, but just puts the word "Array" into the table in the buyernumber and amount fields. It doesn't put the data entered into those boxes in the form.

Comment: Ok. I am giving up on this being a single script solution. I am going to try to make it a two-script method where the first one lists the items and presents input boxes and submits the inputs to the second script that then does the job and redirects back to the first one for a new list. Thanks to everyone for your help! Wish we could get it working. I am against time here and I have wasted far too many hours on this little snot already. Not a paying job but a favor for a friend that needs to be done by the weekend. . .

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether it's one script or two scripts.

Comment: `Array` is what you get when you try to use an array where a single value is required. `$_POST["buyernumber"]` is an array, but `$_POST["buyernumber"][$itemnumber]` should be a number, so it should work correctly.

Comment: What number would it return? The buyernumber or the itemnumber?

Comment: `$itemnumber` is the index into an array of buyer numbers, so of course it returns the buyernumber.